# SVG image doesn't render in echarts toolbox in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, echarts

I'm using the baidu echarts charting library to create a toolbox. I'm setting the icon field of a user-defined tool by passing a link to an svg image which looks like this - `'image://<path>'`. This thing works for all browsers except for IE. IE version is 11.
I tried to load the svg image inside a DOM element and it works fine in IE. It has issues only with echarts.

This is what my toolbox option looks like -

```
option = {
toolbox: {
    show: true,
    orient: 'vertical',
    itemSize: 20,
    height:10,
    width:10,
    top: 'center',
    right: '10%',
    feature: {
        myButton: {
            show: true,
            title: '...',
            icon: 'image://sample.svg',
            onclick: function (){
                alert('clicked')
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: IE11 definitely supports SVG although it has a rendering bug that causes CSS width and height rules not to be respected in some cases. By any chance could IE be rendering your site in Compatibility Mode? Open the developer tools for IE and rule that out before anything else.

Comment: It isn't. Compatibility mode is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got Solution!!! Accept my answer if its Usefull.

IE Not support direct svg file. It support only svg path with out any color. So we need to escape that using the following steeps.

**For an example:**

**Step: 1**
I have taken svg image "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg"
I put it as my button icon its worked in all the browser except IE.To make icon to work in all browser

**Step 2**
Open the svg file and copy only the path.
So I planed to convert it into path. I visited this site https://aydos.com/svgedit/
[image]

Now we having the correct path for the svg file. But the path what we copied from that website will have space between coordinates so we need to replace the "space" with the ",".

**Final Step**
Goto :https://convert.town/replace-spaces-with-commas paste your exported code left side. It automaticaly add space between the coordinates. now you can use that path in Echart it will work in all the browsers.

[image]

That's all it will work fine.

Sample In IE:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Using path instead of image seems to be the only option.